# Let $x_n$ = $((-1)^n +1)/n)$. Describe the subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Let $x_n = $$((-1)^n +1)/n)$. Describe the subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$.

A sequence is $y_n$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ iff there is an increasing function $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $y_n = x_{f(n)}$. For example $y_n = x_{2n}$ is the sequence whose terms are just the even numbered terms of the sequence $x_n$.

Edit:  plugged in 2n for n and got (-1)^2n+1/2n. Knowing anything raised to 2*n will give me an even number, by the definition of an even number. -1*-1 = 1, and -1*-1*-1*-1 = 1, and by these examples you can see that it will always be positive. Giving 1+1/2n = 1/n. Which the person below has shown.

For the second one I have plug in 2n-1 for n. And since the definition of an odd number is 2n-1 you will always get a -1..So -1+1/2n-1 = 0 which this person has shown.

I wasn't sure what to formally write after I have figured this out.

Comment: This question seems completely devoid of personal effort.  What have you done to try to understand the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $n\geq 1$:
$$
x_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^{2n} + 1}{2n} = \frac{2}{2n} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
$$
x_{2n-1} = \frac{(-1)^{2n-1} + 1}{2n-1} = \frac{-1 + 1}{2n-1} = 0
$$
So, the sequence $(y_i)$ defined by $y_i = x_{2i}$ is the sequence $y_i = 1/i$, and the sequence $(z_i)$ defined by $z_i = x_{2i - 1}$ is the zero sequence.